# nginx root points to wrong folder

Tags: nginx

didn't think that this is a complex problem but I didn't get it solved.

I'ld love to point www.mydomain.com/phpMyAdmin/ to /var/www/phpMyAdmin/htdocs/

I did this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     localhost;

    location /phpMyAdmin {
            root    /var/www/phpMyAdmin/htdocs/;

            index   index.php;

            #access_log      /var/www/phpMyAdmin/logs/access.log;
            #error_log       /var/www/phpMyAdmin/logs/error.log;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/sockets/www.socket;
    }
}
```

But the result when calling www.mydomain.com/phpMyAdmin ist that it tries to call

```
/var/www/phpMyAdmin/htdocs/phpMyAdmin/index.php
```

Anyone could help me?

Comment: just curious, shouldn't server_name be www.mydomain.com instead of localhost

Comment: Not necessarily - it's the nginx default - I use it for testing purposes only. The server has no name at the moment - will be master-image for rapid deployment.

Comment: thanks Pascal , was just clarifying for wholly sake of my understanding

Comment: i think you need also change  location /phpMyAdmin to  location /phpMyAdmin/

Answer (score 0):

That is very easy.

Nginx appends `$uri` of location to the `root` directive (`$document_root` variable) .
You can use `alias` directive instead:

```
location /phpMyAdmin {
 index   index.php;
 alias    /var/www/phpMyAdmin/htdocs/;
 access_log      /var/www/phpMyAdmin/logs/access.log;
 error_log       /var/www/phpMyAdmin/logs/error.log;
}
```

But, phpMyAdmin will NOT work, because, it is not a static file.

I believe, you need to specify location for php inside /phpmyadmin:

`location ~ /phpMyAdmin/\.php$`